# Flask Return File Given Data URI

Tags: python, flask, data-uri

Within my flask function I am able to retrieve the data URI (with selenium successfully) using the [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method on a canvas.

I would like to use the data from the data URI object to send a file in my flask method using the send_file flask method.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with it some more here's what solved my problem. I used the [datauri](https://github.com/eclecticiq/python-data-uri) package for python.

Here's a sample route for Flask

```
import datauri    
import io
from flask import Flask, send_file

@app.route('/test', methods=["GET"])
def return_file():
    data_uri = "some_data_uri"
    p = datauri.parse(data_uri)
    return send_file(io.BytesIO(p.data), mimetype=p.media_type)
```

Comment: The answer by David is correct but the link to the package is actually
https://pypi.org/project/python-datauri/